# Copy Text to Clipboard by clicking the text itself

Tags: javascript

So i have a load of text and within the text is words that have brackets around them.

See below:
[image]

At the moment i am doing a pre_replace in PHP to essentially put any text that are in between the [] into a span, where they are then coloured and given a class of clickable.

i essentially want to be able to click on the text and it copies that word to the clipboard.

At the moment i have this **PHP**:

```
$note = preg_replace('%(\[(.+?)\])%m', '<span style="color: #009EC0;" class="hover-cursor clickable">$1</span>', $note);
```

I found this **jQuery** online and just kind of changed the class names to mine:

```
// Copy replace variable to clipboard

document.getElementById('.clickable').addEventListener('click', function(event) 
{
    var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.clickable');

    copyTextarea.select();

    try 
    {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }
});
```

However this gives me an error saying: 
*Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null*

So how can i achieve this?

Comment: Here's your problem: `document.getElementById('.clickable')`, note the `.`. Secondly, this may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: use `getElementByClassname('clickable')`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I assume you mean `getElementsByClassName()` instead. Note that if you do it that way you'd need to loop over the resulting collection, or access it by index.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have removed the `.` but its still giving the error Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. Also that link you provided is where i got this code and tried to adapt it to my code but to no avail :(

Comment: Does an element with an `id` of `clickable` exist in the DOM?

Comment: I think he better can do with jquery. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it does yes, i have added an `id="clickable"` too, im not getting that error anymore as i added an if statement on geting the element by ID, before adding teh listener, so now its not adding the listener because its saying the id of clickable is NULL despite it being there.

Comment: Does the element exist when the page loads, or are you adding it dynamically?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its being added dynamically

Comment: That's your issue now then. You're adding the event listener before the element exists. You need to put it on the element after you've created it in the DOM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah ok, thanks, i will give that a go!